# Flutter: change state of body from fab

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app where I cant to add a new item on ListView by clicking on FAB.
But I want fab and body of MetarialApp be in other classes. I don't want to smash them in one.

I'm trying to change count of children for ListView in Stateful widget, using Notification. But it doesn't work.

How to communicate with different widgets (like add an item to ListView widget by clicking on fab)?

What's the best approach? I've heard about global keys but I don't nderstand how to use them.

```
main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var list = MyList();

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("My App")),
        body: list,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              MyNotification(count: 1).dispatch(context);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add)),
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ListState();
}

class ListState extends State {
  int count = 3;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<MyNotification>(
      onNotification: onCountPush,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: count,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return BodyCard();
          }),
    );
  }

  bool onCountPush(MyNotification notify) {
    setState(() {
      count += notify.count;
    });
    return true;
  }
}

class MyNotification extends Notification {
  final int count;

  const MyNotification({this.count});
}
```

Comment: you should use bloc and streams for this purpose. This will keep your code clean and structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` and `FAB` are properties of `Scaffold`. So when you are trying to control the state of the `body` from `FAB`, the one that should be handling it is not the `body` but the `Scaffold` itself. Look, the `Scaffold` extends `StatefulWidget` and on the other hand the `MyList` extends `StatelessWidget`. Hope you get my point.

```
main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyScaffold(),
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyScaffoldState();
}

class MyScaffoldState extends State {
  int count = 3;

  void changeCount() {
    setState(() {
      count = count == 3 ? 5 : 3;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("My App")),
      body: MyList(count),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: changeCount,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  final int count;

  const MyList(this.count);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          height: 30,
          color: Colors.red,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:**

Later when your states get more complex, you don't wanna stick with using `setState` to manage the states. Like others said, you can learn BLoC, ChangeNotifier or anything that suits you.

Answer (score -1):

you should use Provider or BLoc in your code so you can do that